# Keep text in diferent resolutions

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if it's possible to display a text with same break lines in different resolutions in Flutter. This text will be inside a Container with fixed size, that will be scaled for each device resolution.

For example if this is my text:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
> libero risus, venenatis vitae suscipit nec, pellentesque sit amet
> libero. Curabitur mollis odio quis orci dignissim placerat vitae non
> odio."

It could be displayed like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
 elit. Quisque libero risus, venenatis vitae 
suscipit nec, pellentesque sit amet libero. Curabitur
 mollis odio quis orci dignissim placerat vitae non
 odio.
```

For example, on Instagram stories, texts always keep same break lines in diferent resolutions.

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector;
import 'package:[project_folder]/values.dart';
import 'package:[project_folder]/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:[project_folder]/story_text.dart';

class MyStatefulText extends StatefulWidget {
  StoryText storyText;

  MyStatefulText({
    Key? key,
    required this.storyText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulText> createState() => _MyStatefulTextState();
}

class _MyStatefulTextState extends State<MyStatefulText> {
  double _angle = 0.0;
  double _currentScale = 1.0;
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;

  Matrix4 _matrix = Matrix4(
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.storyText.offset != null) {
      _offset = widget.storyText.offset!;
    }

    _angle = widget.storyText.angle;

    _currentScale = widget.storyText.scale;

    _matrix.row0 = vector.Vector4(_currentScale, 0, 0, 0);
    _matrix.row1 = vector.Vector4(0, _currentScale, 0, 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: _offset.dy,
      left: _offset.dx,
      child: Transform(
        transform: _matrix,
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: _angle,
          child: Container(
            height: widget.storyText.scaledHeight,
            width: widget.storyText.scaledWidth,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: widget.storyText.scaledHeight,
              maxWidth: widget.storyText.scaledWidth,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.purpleLight,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            ),
            child: Text(
              "${widget.storyText.value}",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: AppColors.primary,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
            /*child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              child: Text(
                "${widget.storyText.value}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
            ),*/
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to wrap with FittedBox(). ?

Comment: You can put a line break ('\n') anywhere you want, then wrap the Text widget inside a FittedBox like @WaiHanKo said.

Comment: Yes, I tried with FittedBox, but the result is the same.

Comment: When you're using a preferred size on width & heigh and the font size is the same it will not change unless you change the container size or you have added a dynamic size of the padding, please include your code to see if you have missed something on it.

Comment: I updated my question with my code.